# Using saved map and control the robot with using Python

Tags: ros, slam, python, navigation, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I'm beginner at  using ROS and SLAM algorithm. I would like to ask a question about controling system. I just followed the TF trainings and  mapping navigation on [turtle](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/MappingAndNavigationOnTurtlebot), I can navigate the robot however, what kind of steps should I use to make my mapping and navigation. For example:

- Do mapping.
- Then do something etc.
- Do location

like that.

So I think, I need a launch file for the launch the robot. But how can I use my mapping on that system? I looked at the some tutorials but I could'nt understand.

Have a nice day!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281902/using-saved-map-and-control-the-robot-with-using-python/) by [mustafamertunali](https://answers.ros.org/users/33498/mustafamertunali/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-02-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

mapping: http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping/

navigation: http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2018-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0